# How can I prove that a trigonometric limit does not exist?

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, analysis

How can I prove that a trigonometric limit does not exist, specifically this limit:

$$\lim_{x\to0} x  \cos\left(\frac{1}{x}\right) $$

I have tried to take an ε=1/2 and x=δ/2, arbitrarily and prove that:

$$\lim_{x\to0} x \cos\left(\frac{1}{x}\right)≠0 $$

and
$$\lim_{x\to0} x \cos\left(\frac{1}{x}\right)≠a$$ when $$a>0$$

and so on to prove that by negating the definition, but I don't know if this is the right way to do it or if there is another way to do it.

Thanks

Comment: @josecarlossantos I agree that the question is strictly related and almost a duplicate but it is not exactly a duplicate. I would say it is a slightly different variation.

Comment: The key thing you want to think about for squeeze theorem is "0 times bounded is 0".  Anything that goes to 0 times any bounded function squeezes to 0

Comment: @user Any proof of the fact that $\lim_{x\to0}x\sin\left(\frac1x\right)=0$ also proves that $\lim_{x\to0}x\cos\left(\frac1x\right)=0$ and vice versa.

Answer (score 3):

The limit exists, indeed by squeeze theorem

$$\left|x \cos\left(\frac{1}{x}\right)\right|=\left|x \right|\cdot \left| \cos\left(\frac{1}{x}\right)\right|\le |x| \to 0 \implies x \cos\left(\frac{1}{x}\right) \to 0$$

Comment: Thanks!! I hadn't thought about squeeze theorem

Comment: Yes the key point here is that $\cos (1/x)$ is bounded.